Attach gdb from a docker container to a process running in a different PID namespace
I built a docker image with gcc binutils and gdb debugger installed inside.
I would attach gdb from that docker container to a process inside a lxc container running on the same Linux host. The lxc container uses its own PID namespace, therefore gdb running in the docker container complains that target process and debugger are not in the same PID namespace.
[SR-PCE-251:~]$ docker run -it --pid host --rm --cap-add=SYS_PTRACE --security-opt seccomp=unconfined carlo/ubuntu
root@e7b2db23af34:/#
root@e7b2db23af34:/# id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
root@e7b2db23af34:/# 
root@e7b2db23af34:/# gdb -q attach 11365
attach: No such file or directory.
Attaching to process 11365
[New LWP 24283]
[New LWP 20025]
[New LWP 20024]
[New LWP 19992]
[New LWP 19991]
[New LWP 13974]
[New LWP 13970]
[New LWP 13969]
[New LWP 13968]
[New LWP 13967]
[New LWP 13962]
[New LWP 13958]
[New LWP 13957]
[New LWP 13954]
[New LWP 13952]
[New LWP 13944]
[New LWP 12078]
[New LWP 11822]
[New LWP 11543]
[New LWP 11515]
[New LWP 11489]
[New LWP 11483]
[New LWP 11482]
[New LWP 11477]
[New LWP 11476]

warning: "target:/proc/11365/exe": could not open as an executable file: Operation not permitted.

warning: `target:/proc/11365/exe': can't open to read symbols: Operation not permitted.

warning: Could not load vsyscall page because no executable was specified

warning: Target and debugger are in different PID namespaces; thread lists and other data are likely unreliable.  Connect to gdbserver inside the container.
0x00007f0bf997ac73 in ?? ()
(gdb)

Edited to provide more information based on comments received
[host:/gdb-install]$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root) context=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023
[host:/gdb-install]$ 
[host:/gdb-install]$ ls -la
total 24
drwxrwxr-x.  6 1000 1000 4096 Nov 14 09:32 .
drwxr-xr-x. 30 root root 4096 Nov 14 11:27 ..
drwxrwxr-x.  2 1000 1000 4096 Nov 14 09:32 bin
drwxrwxr-x.  3 1000 1000 4096 Nov 14 09:32 include
drwxrwxr-x.  2 1000 1000 4096 Nov 14 09:32 lib
drwxrwxr-x.  6 1000 1000 4096 Nov 14 09:32 share
[host:/gdb-install]$ 
[host:/gdb-install]$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/gdb-install/bin:/gdb-install/lib
[host:/gdb-install]$ ./bin/gdb
./bin/gdb: error while loading shared libraries: libmpfr.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[host:/gdb-install]$    


You can't do that; the idea of PID namespaces is that a one namespace can't inspect the processes of the other (as long as that's not a fork of the same namespace).
So, you might not have built the most useful container, unless you want to convince docker to not unshare the master PID namespace for that container (docker run --pid=host, iirc). It seems to be a bit antithetical, as you next will want to share the inspected container's mount namespace as well, to actually be able to read executables and libraries. Then you need to convince gdb where to look for these paths… Which in the end means that your GDB container is mostly equivalent to a directory with a script that bends PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH so that a custom GDB can be called from that directory, but more complicated to use in practice.
I'd recommend you don't do that but run a gdbstub in the target container. You can then connect to that as a remote monitor from your local (be it in a container or "global") GDB.

By can't inspect the processes of the other (as long as that's not a fork of the same namespace) do you mean that the latter PID namespace is created by calling clone(2) from a process in the parent PID namespace?

yes, exactly :)

Ok thanks. The point is that I can't install GDB on the host system; that's why I built the docker container. Btw the docker option --pid host does not unshare the master/root/default PID namespace for the docker container. My goal, however, is to run the docker container in the PID namespace of the target process running in the LXC container (the debuggee) in order to attach GDB (running in the docker container) to it.

that's why I said "equivalent to a directory": When you can move a docker image somewhere, you can also do the much less privilege operation of moving a directory somewhere. Anyways, the option for sharing PID namespace with a target container is --pid container:{other container}. It'

Sorry, I don't quite understand your point about moving a directory somewhere on the host system. About the aforementioned docker option for sharing PID namespace with a target container...does it apply to an LXC container as target container as well?

Ah, fair point, I don't know the interaction between LXC and docker there, most likely it doesn't. Yeah, in case sharing the host PID NS with your container doesn't work, and sharing with an LXC container is not implemented, your docker container is simply not fit for its purpose. Simply compile GDB for your host system, and use the PREFIX when configuring it to install it into a subdirectory of your home directory. No special privileges needed, at all.

Software doesn't need to get "installed". It needs to find the libraries it needs, and you need to know how to invoke it. In the case of GDB and binutils, installations into local prefixes are very common and not a problem you need a docker container for. You can just install in a directory, copy that directory to another machine, and use it there – assuming you tell your system that libraries and binaries are in there, through the use of the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH variables.

Sorry, PREFIX in your comment above is the directory's absolute path for the configure --prefix option, right?

yes, that would be the thing to set it, right.

Ok, I managed to build gdb installing it (using make install) inside a directory on a x86_64 machine. Then I copied such a directory on the target machine (host and target are the same machine in my case). However, executing ./gdb from that directory on the target machine, I get an error about a shared library .so not found.

did you set the environment variables I mentioned?

You mean PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variables. Setting the latter with export LD_LIBRARY_PATH= to point to the directory on the  target  machine I am running gdb from, I get another error.

Hm, don't you think that maybe the actual error would be helpful here?

I edited the main question to include info about the error returned.

I'm facing with this problem running gdb: even using ../configure --prefix <install-dir> followed by make and then make install from inside the build directory, the directory tree within <install-dir> does not contain .so shared libraries required from gdb to run.

ah, I must admit I was assuming you'd be doing the build on a system with exactly the same set of libraries installed (e.g. a container) and would catch such things locally

Do you mean a build on a system with the same set of libraries installed as the host where gdb is supposed to run on ? In this case using a container (on the system where gdb is actually built) is the best option, as you said.
